# Удаление элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, как можно скрыть часть кода, показанного в этой картинке:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так, если я нигде не ошибся в переписывании классов, то должно работать:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.u-menucont').find('.u-menuvitem').eq(3).hide();
});
```

Comment: Не работает

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно добавить уникальный идентификатор, по которому можно определить данный конкретный div.

Например, `<div class="u-menuvitem" id="myid-2"></div>`.

Тогда `$("#myid-2").hide()` - скроет элемент, `$("#myid-2").remove()` - удалит его.

Почитайте про [селекторы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B). Например, можно еще сделать по номеру элемента в родителе, если он заранее известен.

Comment: Я пробовал создать идентификатор, но оно не хочет его ставить.Покажите как его можно создать в моем случае?